# Worksheet_change doesn't seem to trigger

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a macro up and running that sorts a pivot table, copies a range of cells out of the table and then pastes those into a second sheet. To be honest, with where I'm at with VBA right now I'm pretty happy with this feat alone. Yet I have more things I want it to do.

What I want to happen is this: The macro I have pastes data into the first empty cells in column A. When this happens I want the macro to enter today's date (preferably in a manner that makes it permanent and won't change to tomorrow's date tomorrow) in the same row in column C and the text "IV020" into column D.

In Sheet9 I have the following code (mainly taken from posts here):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim aCell As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        If Not Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then
            For Each aCell In Target
                If aCell.Value <> "" And aCell.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "" Then
                    aCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "=TODAY()"
                    aCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "IV020"
                End If
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox "Please paste in 1 Column"
        End If
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Yet when things are pasted or entered manually into Column A, nothing happens.

Comment: Is the code in a `Worksheet` module, not a standard module? Also maybe check that events are definitely enabled, in the immediate window type `?Application.EnableEvents` and hit enter, it should return `True`

Comment: Go to the VBE's [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx) ([Ctrl]+G)  and paste in `Application.EnableEvents = True` then hit enter. It may have been disabled, then crashed and never re-enabled.

Comment: ?Application.EnableEvents returns True. I'm fairly certain the code is in a Worksheet module, it's in Sheet9 in the VBAProject window.

Comment: Does your existing macro disable events while it runs?

Comment: @Rory I just looked through the code and no, it doesn't.

Comment: Is Sheet9 the one you're pasting to? If you right-click the sheet tab and choose View code, do you see the code you posted?

Comment: @Rory Yes. I even double checked by selecting other modules in between clicking View code and it is the correct one. I'm starting to become pretty confident there's an issue with my code here.

Comment: Ah - it's very unlikely that this is true: `aCell.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = ""`. Also, you actually want: `aCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date` if you don't want the date to change later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) that is a zero-length string. Even if you tried to put one in manually, it would reset itself to **General**.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        'don't do things until you have to
        On Error GoTo Whoa
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim aCell As Range
        'this processes all of the cells that were changes in column A
        For Each aCell In Intersect(Target, Columns(1))
            'If aCell.Value <> "" And aCell.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "" Then
            If aCell.Value <> "" Then
                aCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date   'possibly Now but likely not "=TODAY()"
                aCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "IV020"
            End If
        Next
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

I've made some minor changes; you will have to decide what you want to do about the .NumberFormat issue.

Comment: This worked, thank you! If I read this correctly the thing that was causing me the biggest issue was actually the .NumberFormat = "" part? (which wasn't really necessary to begin with now that I look at it)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Since one of the conditions was that the number format had to be a zero-length string and a number format can **never** be a zero-length string, you would always get to that point and fail to meet the conditions.